# How to get only filename without .mp3 and .mp4 extension in android?

Tags: java, android

I have audio and video names like this :

```
- azan1(1).mp3 
- Funny.mp4
```

So I need an only AudioName as azan and VideoName as Funny. I am newbie in android and don't know how can I get only filename? How can I achieve this in code.??

Comment: String result = yourString.replace(".mp3","") and same for mp4

Comment: @MHP, String sAudio = audioName.replaceAll("[0-9]",""); for this method how can i added those code??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way to get filename without extension:-

```
if (fileName.indexOf(".") > 0)
   fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Comment: Why I'm getting a negative mark for this question and my reputation is decreasing.

Comment: @AnushaB May be because of related duplicate question.

Comment: @LunarWatcher Seriously!!! Question is right as per coding help in android development.

Comment: @Nitin Patel,So now wht i have to do?

Comment: @LunarWatcher, I'm a fresher I know the logic but in android, i don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: @Nitin Patel, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Java , simple and efficient way to get the filename

`String  resultName= filename.split("\\.")[0].split("\\(")[0];`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by 44kksharma, you can split the String at the `.` to get the extension. The only problem as I can see is if the file name contains `.` elsewhere (for an instance filename.test.mp3) - the file is an mp3 but one could argue `filename.test` is a part of the file name. If you think of it like that, this is the right approach using splitting:

```
String  resultName = filename.split("\\.mp")[0];
```

If you have other extensions, you can do this:

```
String  resultName = filename.split("\\.mp|\\.wav|\\.otherformat")[0];
```

`mp3` and `mp4` with have `mp` in them, therefore files with either extension is guaranteed to have `.mp`.

Using `|` is `or` in regex.

Alternatively, you can use the `replaceAll` method:

```
String result = filename.replaceAll("\\.mp3|\\.mp4", "");
```

`replace` works too, but as it doesn't use regex I find it ends up replacing the wrong chars or ends up screwing up the replacement.

Finally, you could use substring too, but using one-liners is possible with regex(/non-regex using replace) with `split()`, `replace()` and `replaceAll()`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(audioname.contions(.mp3)
{
 String audiostr= audioname.replace(".mp3", "");
}
  if(videoname.contions(.mp4)
{
 String videostr= videoname.replace(".mp3", "");
}
```

Set the String in your required textview

Comment: String sAudio = audioName.replaceAll("[0-9]",""); foe this how can add those lines.

Comment: public static boolean containsDigit(final String s)
{
    if (s != null && !s.isEmpty())
    {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray())
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

Comment: if(containsDigit() == true){  
String sAudio = audioName.replaceAll("[0-9]","");  }......please accept the answer if you find it correct

Comment: Is this correct??  audio_name = audioQuranDetail.getFileName();

            new_audio_name =  audio_name.replaceAll("[0-9]","");

            new_audio_name = new_audio_name.replace(".mp3","");

Comment: which one the answer in comment or which i have posted in the answer also put your code here

Comment: This is my code : 
            audio_name = audioQuranDetail.getFileName();

            new_audio_name =  audio_name.replaceAll("[0-9]","");

          String   replace_new_audio_name = new_audio_name.replace(".mp3","");






            tv_audio_name.setText(replace_new_audio_name);

Comment: have you checked my comment number second and third ..please go through it

Comment: @Suubrabh sharma, the Second one is not working now I have String like this: Azan().mp3 now I have to remove that .mp3 from the string.

Answer (score 0):

[This Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-filename-without-extension#removing-the-extensions-from-a-filename) proposes this nifty two-liner that also correctly works for dotfiles:

```java
public static String removeFileExtension(String filename, boolean removeAllExtensions) {
    if (filename == null || filename.isEmpty()) return filename;    

    return filename.replaceAll("(?<!^)[.]" + (removeAllExtensions ? ".*" : "[^.]*$"), "");
}
```